# Add All Form Fields Value Into one

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is a part of my function that creates selectbox and put the index to each option value.My question is how can i add all these fields (textboxes and selectboxes) value into a specific input type hidden based on submit the form ?
here is my code :

```js
$(function() {

  var createChildDropdown = function(i) {
    var $childDropdown = $('<div />', {
      'class': 'childs'
    });
    $childDropdown.append($('<label />', {
      'for': 'childDropdown-' + i
    }).text('Child age ' + i));
    $childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
      'name': 'childDropdown'
    }));
        var options = [' 1 years old', '2 years old', '3 years old'];
    options.forEach(function(option, index) {
   $childDropdown.find('select').append($('<option />').text(option).attr('value', `,${index}`));


    });
        return $childDropdown;
  };
    var destroyChildDropdown = function($el, i) {
    $el.find('div.childs').get(i).remove();
  };

  $(".button-click-child a").on("click", function() {
    var button = $(this);
    var oldVal = parseInt(button.closest("ul").prev().val());
    var newVal = (button.text() == "+") ? oldVal + 1 : (oldVal > 0) ? oldVal - 1 : 0;
    var total_value = "";
 if(newVal >= 5) return; 
    button.closest("ul").prev().val(newVal);

    $(".cat_textbox").each(function() {
      var cat = $(this).prev('span').text();
    });

    if (oldVal < newVal) {
      $('.childDropdowns').append(createChildDropdown(newVal));
    } else if (oldVal > newVal) {
      destroyChildDropdown($('.childDropdowns'), newVal);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" class="cat_textbox" name="child"  value="0" />

 <ul class="button-group button-click-child">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"><span class="hide">+</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" ><span class="hide">-</span></a></li>
  </ul>
      <div class="childDropdowns"></div>
  <button type="submit">SEND</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I assume you wanted to give an individual ID to each select box. If that's the case, you can just add a unique ID value for each selectbox like this:
`$childDropdown.append($('<select />', {
  'id': 'childDropdown-' + i
  'name' : 'childDropdown-' + i
}));`